# Разбить решение задачки по потокам

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Задачка: Создайте приложение, позволяющие численно рассчитать определенный интеграл, разбив его 
вычисление на несколько потоков. Выберите метод интегрирования – метод прямоугольников. 
Выполните сравнение скорости выполнения расчета для одного, двух, трех и четырех потоков. 
Проверьте правильность численного расчета с аналитическим результатом.

Решить интеграл получилось, но с другой частью задания всё плохо. Не могли бы подсказать с чего начать и как это реализовать?

UPD!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace _13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] count = new int[] { 5, 10, 15, 20 };
            var result = from n in count.AsParallel()
                         select Func(n);

            foreach (var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine("Результат: " + item);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static double Func(int n)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            double pi = Math.PI;
            double h, func;

            double s = 0;

            double a = -pi / 4;
            double b = 0;

            h = (b - a) / n;

            for (double x1 = 0, x = a; x <= b; x += h)
            {
                if (x < b)
                {
                    x1 = x + h / 2;
                    if (x1 >= 2)
                        continue;
                    func = x1 / Math.Pow(Math.Cos(x1), 2);
                    s += func;

                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsed = watch.ElapsedTicks;
            Console.WriteLine("Данный интеграл равен: {0:0.0000}. Кол-во тиков: {1}", s * h, elapsed);
            return s * h; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Читать про [параллельность в Task](https://mobile.developer.com/net/article.php/10916_3827326_3/Going-Parallel-with-the-Task-Parallel-Library-and-PLINQ.htm)

Comment: @NewView Спасибо за информацию. Код обновил. Не могли бы Вы сказать, решение задачи верное или не то?

Comment: В общих чертах да.

Comment: @NewView Благодарю